# Some code is added automatically to my site's header - what is it?

Tags: functions, javascript, html, code, hacked

I tried a lot to understand what adds the javascript code below to my site's header, right after `<head>` in my WordPress website. I don't have any plugin that would do that, it just appeared there and I don't know what it means. In my template there is nothing that would add it. I see it in my page's source, using a browser, nowhere else.

Can you please tell me what it is (what id does)? Is it hacking?
 And maybe how to get rid of it.
 Note: there is a link that I don't add anywhere, but somehow it is present on all my pages, from this website "https://ws.sharethis.com/button/st_insights.js?publisher=4d48b7c5-0ae3-43d4-bfbe-3ff8c17a8ae6&"
 This would be hacking, as it even has a publisher id I don't know. I suppose the code below adds it? how can I get rid of this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/var extsrc=null;
    (function(){function j(){if(b&&g){document.write=k;document.writeln=l;var f=document.createElement("span");f.innerHTML=b;g.appendChild(f);b=""}}function d(){j();for(var f=document.getElementsByTagName("script"),c=0;c<f.length;c++){var e=f[c],h=e.getAttribute("asyncsrc");if(h){e.setAttribute("asyncsrc","");var a=document.createElement("script");a.async=!0;a.src=h;document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(a)}if(h=e.getAttribute("extsrc")){e.setAttribute("extsrc","");g=document.createElement("span");e.parentNode.insertBefore(g,e);document.write=function(a){b+=a};document.writeln=function(a){b+=a;b+="\n"};a=document.createElement("script");a.async=!0;a.src=h;/msie/i.test(navigator.userAgent)&&!/opera/i.test(navigator.userAgent)?a.onreadystatechange=function(){("loaded"==this.readyState||"complete"==this.readyState)&&d()}:-1!=navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox")||"onerror"in a?(a.onload=d,a.onerror=d):(a.onload=d,a.onreadystatechange=d);document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(a);return}}j();document.write=k;document.writeln=l;for(c=0;c<extsrc.complete.funcs.length;c++)extsrc.complete.funcs[c]()}function i(){arguments.callee.done||(arguments.callee.done=!0,d())}extsrc={complete:function(b){this.complete.funcs.push(b)}};extsrc.complete.funcs=[];var k=document.write,l=document.writeln,b="",g="";document.addEventListener&&document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",i,!1);if(/WebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent))var m=setInterval(function(){/loaded|complete/.test(document.readyState)&&(clearInterval(m),i())},10);window.onload=i})();/*]]>*/</script>
```

Comment: Sharethis is a legitimate social sharing tool that may have come integrated in you theme.

Comment: it doesn't. there is no reference or setting for it. that code is not legitimate. if it would be, they will simply add the javascript src, not add such a code.